# Populate table view cells with data from text field in previous view

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, cell

I want to populate the prototype cells in a table view with information that the user has typed into a text field in a previous view controller.  I want to set the title and subtitle of each cell using this data instead of a pre-determined array.  How can I pass data from the text field inside a view controller to the title/subtitle section of a table cell view?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your questions is quite broad, do you want to know how to pass data between controllers? Or how to populate the UITableViewCell? In order to get the answers to the points you are stuck with, please update your question to show what you have done so far, code used etc. This will enable people to help accurately

Answer (score 0):

First of all implement this at the point where you want to segue to your TableViewController:

```
let textFieldString = yourTextField.text ?? ""
performSegueWithIdentifier("exampleID", sender: textFieldString)
```

Now create the right segue in your StoryBoard!

1) [From the whole ViewController to your destination ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4raOy.png)

2) [And don't forget your unique segue-ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mt9a.png)

The delegate method prepareForSegue(...) will be called before you perform the segue. In this method you prepare your destination ViewController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
        let targetvc = segue.destinationViewController as? YourTableViewController
        if let targetvc = targetvc
        {
            let yourTextFieldString = sender as? String
            if let yourTextFieldString = yourTextFieldString
            {
                targetvc.yourTextFieldString = yourTextFieldString
            }
        }
}
```

When the segue to your destination ViewController is performed, your variable (here in this case "yourTextFieldString") has the previous set data.

```
class yourTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    var yourTextFieldString = "" // This variable has the previous set data
     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
         super.viewDidLoad()
     }
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath)
         cell.textLabel.text = yourTextFieldString
         return cell
    }
}
```

Now adjust your prototype cell (don't forget the right identifier) and you're done.